# Struct doesn't return correct value

Tags: c, struct, return

When I run my code in debug mode I can see that the correct values from:

```
createBooking("SOME NAME", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
```

is sent to my struct. But when I try to call for something in my struct I can't see the value. The `printf` is just printing 0 and not 2 as it should. Is it something from my `printf` in `main()` that I'm missing? Or what could it be? My teacher has been looking at the code, and he can't find the problem either.

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "functions.h"

int main() {
    struct Booking booking;
    createBooking("SOME NAME", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
    printf("%d", booking.pNumber);  

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

functions.c:

```
#include "functions.h"

struct Booking createBooking(char *aName, int aPNumber, int aStartWeek, int aStopWeek,
                             int aCabNr, int aCabType, int aLiftcard, double aTotCost)
{
    struct Booking booking = *(struct Booking*)malloc(sizeof(struct Booking));

    strncpy(booking.name, aName, strlen(aName) + 1);
    booking.pNumber = aPNumber;
    booking.startWeek = aStartWeek;
    booking.stopWeek = aStopWeek;
    booking.cabNr = aCabType;
    booking.cabType = aCabType;
    booking.liftCard = aLiftcard;
    booking.totCost = aTotCost;

    return booking;
}
```

functions.h:

```
#ifndef functions_h
#define functions_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Booking {
    char name[30];
    int pNumber;
    int startWeek;
    int stopWeek;
    int cabNr;
    int cabType;
    int liftCard;
    double totCost;
} booking;

struct Booking createBooking(char *aName, int aPNumber, int aStartWeek, int aStopWeek, 
                             int aCabNr, int aCabType, int aLiftcard, double aTotCost);
int bookBooking(struct Booking b);

#endif
```

Comment: So what's the result of your printf?

Comment: Edited in question! printf is printing 0 and not 2 as it should.

Comment: This doesn't do what I imagine you think it does: `struct Booking booking = *(struct Booking*)malloc(sizeof(struct Booking));` and it doesn't look like you need to do something as complex as that to do what you want.

Comment: Aside: recommend revising your naming conventions. Look up Hungarian Notation, and Camel Notation. The variable `int pNumber;` suggests it is a pointer, but it isn't. The arguments to `createBooking` all start with `a` but to what purpose? The `a` does not help to distinguish `char*` from `int` and `double` arguments.

Comment: `strncpy(booking.name, aName, strlen(aName)+1);` is a bug. Apart from being unnecessarily verbose (`strcpy(booking.name, aName);` has the same effect) it will overflow if the name is longer than 29.

Comment: @pottsork, if your question is answered, please accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you declare struct like so:

```
struct Booking booking;
```

That declares a struct with undefined values - in most compilers NULL/0
Than you call createBooking that allocates and returns a new struct. And you disregard the return value:

```
createBooking("SOME NAME", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
```

Than you printf the unallocated struct:

```
printf("%d", booking.pNumber);
```

And of course it returns 0 or something unexpected.
What you need to do is this:

```
struct Booking booking = createBooking("SOME NAME", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
printf("%d", booking.pNumber);
```

And as rightfully noticed in the comment by M.M, you don't need to do dynamic allocation inside the function, all you need to do is this:

```
struct Booking createBooking(char *aName, int aPNumber, int aStartWeek, int aStopWeek, int aCabNr, int aCabType, int aLiftcard, double aTotCost)
{
    struct Booking booking;

    strncpy(booking.name, aName, strlen(aName) + 1);
    booking.pNumber = aPNumber;
    booking.startWeek = aStartWeek;
    booking.stopWeek = aStopWeek;
    booking.cabNr = aCabType;
    booking.cabType = aCabType;
    booking.liftCard = aLiftcard;
    booking.totCost = aTotCost;

    return booking;
}
```

Comment: also, inside the function, `struct Booking booking = *(struct Booking*)malloc(sizeof(struct Booking));` should actually read `struct Booking booking;`

Answer (score 0):

Your function `createBooking` should allocate a booking from the heap and return a pointer to it. You could also have a function `initBooking` that takes a pointer to a booking and the values to initialize it.

Here is an example of both ways:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Booking *initBooking(struct Booking *bp,
                            char *aName, int aPNumber, int aStartWeek, int aStopWeek,
                            int aCabNr, int aCabType, int aLiftcard, double aTotCost)
{
    if (bp) {
        size_t len = strlen(aName);
        if (len >= sizeof(bp->name))
            len = sizeof(bp->name) - 1;
        memcpy(bp->name, aName, len);
        bp->name[len] = '\0';
        bp->pNumber = aPNumber;
        bp->startWeek = aStartWeek;
        bp->stopWeek = aStopWeek;
        bp->cabNr = aCabType;
        bp->cabType = aCabType;
        bp->liftCard = aLiftcard;
        bp->totCost = aTotCost;
    }
    return bp;
}

struct Booking *createBooking(char *aName, int aPNumber, int aStartWeek, int aStopWeek,
                              int aCabNr, int aCabType, int aLiftcard, double aTotCost)
{
    return initBooking(malloc(sizeof(struct Booking),
                       aName, aPNumber, aStartWeek, aStopWeek,
                       aCabNr, aCabType, aLiftcard, aTotCost);
}

int main() {
    struct Booking booking;

    initBooking(&booking, "SOME NAME", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
    printf("%d", booking.pNumber);  

    struct Booking *bp;

    bp = createBooking(&booking, "SOME NAME", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
    printf("%d", bp->pNumber);  

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn your compiler warnings on/up and it will give you a lot of help.  You have a number of bugs:

1. allocating a pointer and referring to it without indirection in createbooking.
2. writing into a fixed-length char[30] buffer without testing the size of the input.
3. Setting fields in booking using . instead of -> pointer notation.
4. returning booking (a pointer) when you declare the return value as a value type (the entire struct).
5. ignoring the return value of createBooking.

All of these can be caught by the compiler if you have the warnings on.